# Angestellte oder Angestellter?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, gender

Hier auf dieser Seite (https://bit.ly/2JvtYca) ist angezeigt, das Wort " *Angestellte* " kann für beide Männer und Frauen benutzt werden.
Aber hier (https://bit.ly/2xy8iXe) besagt, " *Angestellte* " ist nur für Frauen und das entsprechende Wort für Männer ist " *Angestellter* ".

Verstehe ich das falsch oder etwas fehlt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Angestellte(r)" ist ein substantiviertes Adjektiv, daher kann es stark oder schwach flektiert auftreten, abhängig davon, ob ein Artikel vorhanden ist. Daher:

Ein Angestellter (männlich, stark)
Eine Angestellte (weiblich, stark)

Der Angestellte (männlich, schwach)
Die Angestellte (weiblich, schwach)

Comment: stark (*ein*) oder schwach (*der*) oder gemischt (*kein*, *unser*), siehe z.B. http://deutsche-rechtschreibung.org/flexion/Angestellte

Comment: Der Vollständigkeit halber sollte noch der Plural erwähnt werden. "Die Angestellten" bzw. "Angestellte".

Answer (score 3):

Angestellte kann Frauen oder mehrere Personen beschreiben:

- Die Angestellte (F) hat Geburtstag
- Angestellte (M/F) haben ein Recht auf Urlaub

---

**Edit:**
Nach Kommentar von User Björn Friedrich:

- Der Angestellte (M) sitzt am Fenster

Comment: _Angestellte_ kann auch Männer beschreiben: _"Der Angestellte kam zu spät."_

Answer (score 2):

Keine der bisherigen Antworten ist vollständig.

Daher trage ich hier alle möglichen Fälle zusammen, in denen das Substantiv *Angestellte*, das durch Nominalisierung aus dem Adjektiv *angestellt* hervorgegangen ist, auftreten kann. Es sind dies:

- **stark, Plural:** „Viele *Angestellte* fehlten heute.“
- **stark, weiblich Singular:** „Eine *Angestellte* fehlte heute.“
- **schwach, männlich Singular:** „Der *Angestellte* fehlte heute.“
- **schwach, weiblich Singular:** „Die *Angestellte* fehlte heute.“

(Rein theoretisch wäre auch **schwach, sächlich Singular** möglich, sofern man einen Kontext hat, in dem *das Angestellte* verwenden möchte.)

Answer (score -1):

Angestellter ist männlich singular

Angestellte kann sowohl weiblich singular als auch geschlechtsneutral plural sein.

Comment: _Angestellte_ kann ebenfalls männlich Singular sein: _"Der Angestellte kam zu spät."_